# Python UnicodeEncodeError when reading a file

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, decoding

I've searched for hours to fix this bug, but none of the online solution solved my issue.

When executing this piece of code on Python 3.6:

```
# encoding=utf-8
f = open("x.htm", "r", -1, "utf-8", 'ignore') 
s = f.read()
print(s)
```

I get following error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xfc' in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)

I do not even know why it is using ascii codec?

I am using a normal html file, only containing utf-8 characters also specified as charset within the file (it looks normal when opened by a common browser)

I already found a workaround:

```
s = f.read().encode('utf-8').decode("ascii", "ignore")
```

The problem so far is data loss, because of the ignore tag, when using the replace tag, than following error occurs:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 37-38: ordinal not in range(128)

I have a normal html file which can correctly utf-8 decoded by my browser and editor, I try to open this file in python with utf-8 - then some unicode error with ascii occurs?

Comment: The problem is probably with the `print`, not the `read`. If your terminal is not set to use UTF-8, `print` is trying to encode `s` using `ascii`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Indeed, I absolutely forgot to check my terminal settings. In my standard terminal it worked without any problems. So I checked in VSCode the stdout encoding with print(sys.stdout.encoding), and voila I got as answer US-ASCII. Please post your comment as answer so I can close this question.